# How to create a Flap-up Info page on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4

I remember seeing multiple apps that will have a little *i* on the bottom of the screen, and the corner will flap up a bit to show a few things, such as a masthead. **The Maps app (before iOS6) has what I'm talking about in the bottom right corner. It shows allows you to print maps and drop the pin, etc.**

I want to do exactly that. I want that corner to flap up, and show that I created it, and anything else. Is there any way I can create this? It can be text-based, image-based, anything. I tried something, but it didn't work:

I created the *i* (made a 'Round Rect Button' and turned it into an 'Info Light button), and tried making a new window in the .xib, and linking them together, but it didn't seem to work.

TL;DR: How do I create the info page that flaps up from the bottom right/left corner?

BTW: I'm using XIB, not storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is fairly easy. You have to present your viewcontroller modally and set the transition mode:

```
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
```

You can try to start a new project....select Utility Application....it will make a flip between the two viewcontrollers....just change the transistionStyle to what I wrote above then it should curl up like in the maps app

Comment: how about if I'm already in a project? I'm in a XIB Single View Project. Is there any way I can do this.

Comment: My recommendation would be to create an additional viewcontroller with a xib file that you can show under the curlup. That shouldn't be a problem even though if you decided only to have one viewcontroller in your project. It is by far the easiest way to implement...if you want to try to do some animations between views you can maybe look here. I'm not sure if it will describe what you need though: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html